# Loop through an two arrays simultaneously and pass a first element of each array to the function at a time using angular js [new to angular]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

```
vm.array1.push(content1);
vm.array2.push(content2);
```

I have a above two arrays with a data of objects pushed at each time and the data modal of each array looks like this

```
vm.array1=[object1,object2,object3]
vm.array2=[object1,object2,object3]
```

I need to pass only object of first element of array1 with the object of first element of array2 to the function.

```
vm.save(a,b){
//save functionality success by calling API
}
```

variables a,b should contain only the first elements of both the array simultaneously followed by second elements then third...

How can i pass only objects but not arrays to the function using angularJS?

Comment: do you mean to call a function inside loop?

Comment: No...function should be called outside the loop@brk

Comment: ok then when will the function called with second elements?

Comment: so,the function should be looped?

Comment: Assuming they have the same length, loop over one of the arrays and just pass the items at the corresponding indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `array1` and `array2` are of same length. This should work.

```js
var vm = {
  save: function(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b)
  }
};
vm.array1 = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}];
vm.array2 = [{
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 5
}, {
  id: 6
}];

vm.array1.forEach(function(a1, i) {
  vm.save(a1, vm.array2[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the simplest you can do following. (This solution will modify your arrays)

```
do{
   vm.save(vm.array1.shift(), vm.array2.shift()){
   //save functionality success by calling API
   }
}while(vm.array1.length>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz check may this will be work:-

```
for(var i=0;i<=vm.array1.length;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<=vm.array2.length;j++)
    {
        if(i==j)
        vm.save(vm.array1[i].content1,vm.array2[j].content2){
        //save functionality success by calling API
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this very inefficient as you could only loop j^i times instead of i times.