# JavaScript Matching one array with another?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, loops

[image]

above i have the picture of my arrays, below code i have mapped 2 sets of array .Purpose of this function is to make '**_polygons**' empty array. i have a rest service which is '**this.siAsset.updateComponent(_id, _polygons)**' that is designed to update each asset. only thing is, i cant seem to pass an array of data to the update component service i have, its designed to take one id and one object as a parameter (if there is a way around , please provide) as you can see by the picture, both _id and _polygons have  arrays of id's an arrays of objects. Question is, how can i loop and match to call the rest to go through each id and object instead of calling by writing the code 9 times like this.siAsset.updateComponent(_id[0], _polygons[0]) ...this.siAsset.updateComponent(_id[9], _polygons[9])

```js
  deleteAllZones = () => {
        let assetVal = this.asset.$$state.value
        console.log('tenant', assetVal)
        let _polygons = assetVal.map(function (a) {
             a.polygon = []
             return a
        })
        console.log('a',_polygons)
        let _id = assetVal.map(function (a) {
            let id = a.id
            return id
        })
        console.log('id',_id)
        
        

        let message = this.$filter('translate')('SI-MESSAGES.DELZONE-MSG');
        let title = this.$filter('translate')('SUBHEADER.DELZONE-TITLE');
        let button = this.$filter('translate')('BUTTON.DELETE');
        this.siAlertDialog.confirm(message, title, button)
            .then(() => {
                this.siAsset.updateComponent(_id, _polygons).then(() => {
                    this.toastIt.simple(this.$filter('translate')('SI-MESSAGES.ZONE-DELETED'))

                }, (err) => {
                    this.siAlertDialog.error();
                }
                )
            })
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an two arrays simultaneously and pass a first element of each array to the function at a time using angular js \[new to angular\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644975/loop-through-an-two-arrays-simultaneously-and-pass-a-first-element-of-each-array)

Comment: i can see its similar  mine is one parameter array of numbers and second parameter is array of objects. your solution might still work. I couldn't visualize it . Would u give me an example with mine? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet doesn't work. I've made dummy entries. This should give you an idea. Basically, you need to loop over one array and use the index to find corresponding items in the second

```js
// Mocking data here
let assetVal = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  }
]
let _polygons = assetVal.map(function(a) {
  a.polygon = []
  return a
})
//console.log('a', _polygons)
let _id = assetVal.map(function(a) {
  let id = a.id
  return id
})
//console.log('id', _id)
// Mocking done

let updateComponent = (id, polygon) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({
      id,
      polygon
    })
  })
}

_id.forEach((id, i) => {
  updateComponent(id, _polygons[i]).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
})
```

Also, by looking at your code, it doesn't look like your `updateComponent` method needs `id` to be passed as a parameter as it is already present in the `polygon` as well. Maybe you want to refactor that.