# two array input into object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, i want to get no_anggota, nama_lahir and tgl_lahir  from array isiuser, and i want to insert to ZZZ .

```js
isiseat = [
    [{ x: 0, y: 0, val: 1 },
    { x: 1, y: 0, val: 1 },
    { x: 2, y: 0, val: 1 }]
    [{ x: 0, y: 1, val: 1 },
    { x: 1, y: 1, val: 1 },
    { x: 2, y: 1, val: 1 }]
    [{ x: 0, y: 2, val: 1 },
    { x: 1, y: 2, val: 1 },
    { x: 2, y: 2, val: 1 }]
];
isiuser = [ { no_anggota: '12345', nama_lahir: ' Agus dwi', tgl_lahir: '04-09-2018'}, 
            { no_anggota: '12345', nama_lahir: 'Septano', tgl_lahir: '15-08-2018'},
            { no_anggota: '12345', nama_lahir: 'Septian putra', tgl_lahir: '15-08-2018'}
        ];

isiseat.forEach((item1) => {
    item1.forEach((item2) => {
        var detaildata = {};
        detaildata.x = item2.x
        detaildata.y = item2.y
        detaildata.val = item2.val
        detaildata.no_anggota = 'ZZZ'
        detaildata.nama_lahir = 'ZZZ'
        detaildata.tgl_lahir = 'ZZZ'
        detaildata.jadwal = req.body.jadwal
        detaildata.section = req.body.section
        var savedata = new DetailBooking(detaildata);
        savedata.save()
    })
});
```

Comment: Please re-read your questions and make proper corrections as it is not making any sense as of now.

Comment: If you can add your desired result, it would make easier to understand.

Comment: i wan to like this https://i.imgur.com/LayDNY1.png

Comment: `isiseat`needs `,` between entries

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulk insert [bulk insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/)

```
var dataArray = [];
var isiseat = [
            [
                { x: 0, y: 0, val: 1 },
                { x: 1, y: 0, val: 1 },
                { x: 2, y: 0, val: 1 }
            ],
            [
                { x: 0, y: 1, val: 1 },
                { x: 1, y: 1, val: 1 },
                { x: 2, y: 1, val: 1 }
            ],
            [
                { x: 0, y: 2, val: 1 },
                { x: 1, y: 2, val: 1 },
                { x: 2, y: 2, val: 1 }
            ]
        ]
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
isiseat.forEach((item1) => {
    item1.forEach((item2) => {
        var detaildata = {};
        detaildata.x = item2.x
        detaildata.y = item2.y
        detaildata.val = item2.val
        detaildata.no_anggota = 'ZZZ'
        detaildata.nama_lahir = 'ZZZ'
        detaildata.tgl_lahir = 'ZZZ'
        detaildata.jadwal = 'sssss'
        detaildata.section = 'sssssss'
        bulk.insert(detaildata);
    })
});
bulk.execute();
```

my saved data look like this

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b61aab063727f69dc5ad1b8"),
    "x" : 0.0,
    "y" : 0.0,
    "val" : 1.0,
    "no_anggota" : "ZZZ",
    "nama_lahir" : "ZZZ",
    "tgl_lahir" : "ZZZ",
    "jadwal" : "sssss",
    "section" : "sssssss"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b61aab063727f69dc5ad1b9"),
    "x" : 1.0,
    "y" : 0.0,
    "val" : 1.0,
    "no_anggota" : "ZZZ",
    "nama_lahir" : "ZZZ",
    "tgl_lahir" : "ZZZ",
    "jadwal" : "sssss",
    "section" : "sssssss"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `isiseat` and `isiuser` arrays are of the same length, you can pass the index parameter to the `forEach` function. [(See "Loop through an two arrays simultaneously")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44644975/5037430)

Therefore you could pass the index to your first `forEach` function:

```
// Index passed here
isiseat.forEach((item1, index) => {
  item1.forEach((item2) => {
    var detaildata = {
      x: item2.x,
      y: item2.y,
      val: item2.val,
      // ...And then access the `isiuser` array accordingly 
      no_anggota: isiuser[index].no_anggota,
      nama_lahir: isiuser[index].nama_lahir,
      tgl_lahir: isiuser[index].tgl_lahir,
      jadwal: req.body.jadwal,
      section: req.body.section
    };
    // console.log to see results
    console.log(detaildata)
    var savedata = new DetailBooking(detaildata);
    savedata.save()
  })
});
```